# Template Class Inheritence

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, compiler-errors

I have a template class called Stack which I'm trying to inherit from.
I do this:

```
template <class T> class Queue : public Stack
{ };
```

but the compiler says:

> error: expected class-name before '{' token

What's wrong?

Comment: Please add Stack definition, and the line where the compiler shows the error

Comment: You should definitely work on your accept-rate to give others a motivation for answering your questions. If you don't know what I'm talking about, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 7):

If Stack is a template, then you have to provide it's template arguments when you reference it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is possibly in your Stack class.  The compiler has only tried to compile it now because it is being used.